# VB macro to send mail without opening Lotus notes

Tags: vba, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I want to send a mail with a vbscript without opening Lotus Notes UI. I managed to write a script that allows to send email with attachments and everything works fine. However the application is launched when I run the macro and I want it to work silenty (without launching the application).

Here is my code:

```
Dim noSession As Object
Dim noDatabase As Object
Dim noDocument As Object
Dim paths() As String
    
'Instantiate the Lotus Notes COM's Objects.
Set MailSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
Set MailDatabase = MailSession.GetDatabase("", "")

'If Lotus Notes is not open then open the mail-part of it.
If MailDatabase.IsOpen = False Then MailDatabase.OPENMAIL
    
'Create the list of recipients.
vaRecipients = VBA.Array(EmailTo)
vaCCRecipients = VBA.Array(EmailCC)
vaBCCRecipients = VBA.Array(EmailBCC)
Set MailDoc = MailDatabase.CreateDocument
MailDoc.Form = "Memo"
MailDoc.sendTo = vaRecipients
MailDoc.CopyTo = vaCCRecipients
MailDoc.BlindCopyTo = vaBCCRecipients
MailDoc.Subject = Subject
MailDoc.Body = Body
MailDoc.SAVEMESSAGEONSEND = True
MailDoc.ReplyTo = Sender
MailDoc.SMTPOriginator = Sender
MailDoc.Sender = Sender
MailDoc.principal = Sender
MailDoc.inetprincipal = Sender
MailDoc.from = Sender
MailDoc.inetfrom = Sender
MailDoc.displayfrom = Sender
    
paths = Split(AttachmentPaths, ";")
Dim richTextItem As Object
Dim AttachmentPath As String
For i = LBound(paths()) To UBound(paths())
    AttachmentPath = paths(i)
    Set richTextItem = MailDoc.CreateRichTextItem("Attachment" & i)
    Call richTextItem.EmbedObject(1454, "", AttachmentPath)
Next i
    
MailDoc.Send 0, vaRecipients
    
'Release objects from memory.
Set noDocument = Nothing
Set noDatabase = Nothing
Set noSession = Nothing
MsgBox "The e-mail has successfully been created and distributed", vbInformation
```

The problem is that Lotus notes UI is launched everytime I run the macro because of this line:

`If MailDatabase.IsOpen = False Then MailDatabase.OPENMAIL`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are wrong in your assumption that OPENMAIL is the cause for the client opening.

The real problem is your usage of the OLE- based objectclass "Notes.NotesSession".
If you really want to get away without opening the notes- Client you need to use the COM- based objectclass "Lotus.NotesSession" or "Domino.NotesSession".

The problem is: When using Lotus.NotesSession you need to initialize your session with password yourself (your password has to be in the code) or a black DOS- Prompt will ask your for your Notes- Password. When using "Notes.NotesSession", the client itself is used for authentication. That is why it opens when running your code. If it is already open, nothing will happen.

You can check [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32382331/notes-notessession-vs-domino-notessession-password-prompt) for more details, its principles are still true.

The code is nearly the same as with the other class, you also need a properly installed Notes Client. You just need to initialize the session instead of just using it:

```
Set MailSession = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession")
MailSession.Initialize( "yourpassword" )
```

If you don't enter a password then you will be prompted for it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you have an example of code with Domino.NotesSession? where I can hardcod my username and password?

Comment: There is a setting in the User Security - a checkbox labeled "Don't prompt for password from other Notes-based programs." It also says in parenthesis, "reduces security", which it does, but if you're willing to take the risk that a user might download malware that silently reads and writes email (and possibly other things), then the password prompt can be avoided. I don't recommend it, but it's there and it deserves mention.

Comment: You are right @Richard, but this checkmark imho only is relevant if the id is already unlocked (Notes Client started), without started client you will still have to enter a password...

Comment: Yes, that's true.